# deferencing void * pointer during memcpy, want to know how this can be solved?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm copying the src from buf index 5. I got the warning at src buffer. Just want to know what mistake I'm doing here?

This the warning message I got. **warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer**

```
uint8_t grx_buf[1024];
const void *buf;
uint8_t len = 12;

memcpy(&grx_buf[grx_count], &buf[5], len);
                                ^
```

When I typecast this to destination buffer data type I got this

```
memcpy(&grx_buf[grx_count], *(uint8_t*)&buf[5], len);
```

Warning:

> note: expected ‘const void * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘unsigned char’
>
> ```
> extern void *memcpy (void *__restrict __dest, const void *__restrict __src,
> ```

Comment: Any reason why `buf` is a `void*`?

Comment: The message can't be more clear! If you don't understand it, you should learn what `void *` is and what not.

Comment: Because void * is the buf I get from callback in which type is generic. Then I type cast to destination data type.

Comment: Typecast the *pointer variable* before using array indexing.

Comment: Read [ask] and provide a [mcve]!

Comment: And don't dereference the pointer.

Comment: Alright thanks programming dude.

Comment: Here I m asking for the recommend suggestions. I know casting the void * will solve the problem. I want to know is it best or ugly thing to do?

Comment: @LethalProgrammer first clarify what an array subscript on a `void *` is supposed to express here? It doesn't make sense without a data type ...

Comment: @LethalProgrammer: It depends on the system architecture and more details. However, we are not a consulting site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it almost correct!

```
memcpy(&grx_buf[grx_count], *(uint8_t*)&buf[5], len);
```

Instead of this, you should pass pointer variables to `src` and `dst` arguments of memcpy.
In this statement, in the second argument (the `src` argument) you are doing hte following:

- Dereferencing void* to get the 5th element. This is the same error you got the first time.
- Taking its address.
- Casting to uint8_t* (what you actually want)
- Dereferencing again, so you have an uint8_t, instead of a pointer, which is what the memcpy function expcts.

What you actually want, is the following:

```
memcpy(&grx_buf[grx_count], (uint8_t*)buf+5, len);
```

or alternatively, trying to follow your syntax:

```
memcpy(&grx_buf[grx_count], &((uint8_t*)buf)[5], len);
```

- Cast buf to uint8_t*
- Take the 5th element of a complete type, so you get an uint8_t
- Take its address, so you have a pointer to uint8_t, which is what memcpy expects.

---

Edit: Note that your buffer is of type `const void*`, thus all the pointer casts should be to type `const uint8_t *` instead of to `uint8_t*`, in order to keep constness consistent.

Alternatively, an easier way (less verbose) is to create a new variable:

```
const uint8_t *buf8=buf; //No cast required, since in C (not C++) `void*` can be implicitly converted to any type.
```

Now you should use buf8 as follows:

```
memcpy(&grx_buf[grx_count], buf8+5, len);
```

Comment: @LethalProgrammer Check the edit, in order to keep constness consistent, since the cast to `uint8_t *` removes the `const` qualifier of your buffer, leading to potential problems later on

Answer (score 2):

Check the data types.

`buf` is a `void *`, and you cannot dereference a pointer which is not a pointer to a complete type. `void` is an incomplete type which cannot be completed, hence compiler cannot perform any pointer arithmetic on that.

You need to cast `buf` to a complete type, then dereference it. If it's needed, you can cast back the result of unary `&` to `const void *`, again.

---

That said, the code does not look proper. It does not have memory allocation, and indexing on a generic pointer does not make much sense either. if the `void *` is used as a generic pointer (or container), then you need to cast it back to the original type before operating on it.

Comment: Casts are most times not the solution!

Comment: @Olaf OK, so in this case, what do you suggest sir?

Comment: @Olaf casts *are* often a solution dealing with `void *` when attempting something generic, even if they should normally be implicit. I agree having an array subscript on a `void *` looks *fishy*.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: `void *` need not (and should not) be cast to other pointers. For clarity, one assigns the `void *` to a pointer with the actual type **once** and uses that pointer lateron **iff** one has to use it. But I'm not convinced `void *` is really necessary for the code shown. I suspect a bad interface design before I accept this.

Comment: @Olaf with assignment the cast is there, but implicit. That's what I meant.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: A conversion is not a cast!

Comment: @Olaf in case of a possible implicit conversion, both are equivalent.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: None. Maybe I should leave this site. Quality seems to be no criterion anymore. I removed the DV on your answer, feel free to write whatever you want, including chatting about knitting.

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
memcpy(&grx_buf[grx_count], *(uint8_t*)&buf[5], len);
```

as a second argument instead of passing the pointer you are dereferencing it.
Thats why you get that warning:

> note: expected ‘const void * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘unsigned char’

The function expect a pointer, but you pass unsigned char.
Change the function call with this:

```
memcpy(&grx_buf[grx_count], (uint8_t*)&buf[5], len);
```